# Add frequency counts for missing choromosomes as 0

Tags: r, bioinformatics

This is cn0 file and frequency values according to chromosome

```
  $gw6.00033
 X  Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
  1 gw6.00033  chr1:    cn=0         1
 12 gw6.00033  chr2:    cn=0         1
 16 gw6.00033  chr4:    cn=0         1
 20 gw6.00033  chr6:    cn=0         1

   $gw6.0006
  X Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
  26 gw6.0006  chr1:    cn=0         1
  29 gw6.0006  chr10    cn=0         3
  31 gw6.0006  chr11    cn=0         2
  34 gw6.0006  chr13    cn=0         1
  37 gw6.0006  chr15    cn=0         1
  38 gw6.0006  chr16    cn=0         1
  41 gw6.0006  chr2:    cn=0         1
  47 gw6.0006  chr3:    cn=0         1
  57 gw6.0006  chr8:    cn=0         2
```

This is the code in R :-

```
sp <- split(cn0, cn0$sample_name)
N <- 22
sp <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
M <- as.numeric(sub("[^[:digit:]]+([[:digit:]]+)[^[:digit:]]*", "\\1",     DF$Chr_no))
Chr_no <- sub("[[:digit:]]+[^[:digit:]]*$", "", DF$Chr_no)
Chr_no <- paste0(Chr_no, 1:N)
Chr_no <- ifelse(nchar(Chr_no) == 4, paste0(Chr_no, ":"), Chr_no)
sample_name <- rep(DF$sample_name[1], length(Chr_no))
res <- data.frame(sample_name, Chr_no)
res$Frequence <- 0
res$Frequence[1:N %in% M] <- DF$Frequence
res
  })
   abc <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(sp, '[[', 'Frequence')))
    names(abc) <- sp[[1]]$Chr_no
```

it gives the output :-

```
 $gw6.00033
      Sample_Name Chr_No Frequence
    1  gw6.00033  chr1:         1
    2  gw6.00033  chr2:         1
    3  gw6.00033  chr3:         0
    4  gw6.00033  chr4:         1
    5  gw6.00033  chr5:         0
    6  gw6.00033  chr6:         1
    7  gw6.00033  chr7:         0
    8  gw6.00033  chr8:         0
    9  gw6.00033  chr9:         0


$gw6.0006
 Sample_Name Chr_No Frequence
1  gw6.0006  chr1:         1
2  gw6.0006  chr2:         3?
3  gw6.0006  chr3:         2?
4  gw6.0006  chr4:         0
5  gw6.0006  chr5:         0
6  gw6.0006  chr6:         0
7  gw6.0006  chr7:         0
8  gw6.0006  chr8:         1?
```

It gives result but with wrong frequencies when it create a matrix it puts the missing chromosomes on its place but not in frequency it should place 0 corresponding to the missing chromosomes. For sample gw6.00033 it creates right data frame because all chromosomes are in ascending order but for sample gw6.0006 the frequencies are wrong what improvement is required in the code.

Comment: Is cn0 a list of data.frames? Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: cn0 is a file that contain data and this data will be loaded  as data frame in R then spit data as list of data frames in sp.

Comment: Are you trying to add missing chroms per sample?

Comment: Yes,This program can add the missing chromosome but it should add 0 as the frequency of the missing chromosome But this program is adding 0 at the end so the chromosomes and there frequencies are not matching

Comment: What happens to "chr13"? Does it become "chr13:", why do you need `":"` ?

Comment: actually I extract data with " : " so I remain it as it was. there is no need of " : " It will remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *tidyr::complete*:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "X  Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
1 gw6.00033  chr1:    cn=0         1
12 gw6.00033  chr2:    cn=0         1
16 gw6.00033  chr4:    cn=0         1
20 gw6.00033  chr6:    cn=0         1
26 gw6.0006  chr1:    cn=0         1
29 gw6.0006  chr10    cn=0         3
31 gw6.0006  chr11    cn=0         2
34 gw6.0006  chr13    cn=0         1
37 gw6.0006  chr15    cn=0         1
38 gw6.0006  chr16    cn=0         1
41 gw6.0006  chr2:    cn=0         1
47 gw6.0006  chr3:    cn=0         1
57 gw6.0006  chr8:    cn=0         2", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# ordered factor vector
allChroms <- factor(c(paste0("chr", 1:9, ":"), paste0("chr", 10:22)),
                    levels = c(paste0("chr", 1:9, ":"), paste0("chr", 10:22)))

res <- complete(df1[, -1], 
                Sample_Name,
                Chr_No = allChroms,
                fill = list(Copy_No = "cn=0", Frequence = 0))

res
# # A tibble: 44 x 4
#    Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
#    <chr>       <chr>  <chr>       <dbl>
#  1 gw6.00033   chr1:  cn=0            1
#  2 gw6.00033   chr2:  cn=0            1
#  3 gw6.00033   chr3:  cn=0            0
#  4 gw6.00033   chr4:  cn=0            1
#  5 gw6.00033   chr5:  cn=0            0
#  6 gw6.00033   chr6:  cn=0            1
#  7 gw6.00033   chr7:  cn=0            0
#  8 gw6.00033   chr8:  cn=0            0
#  9 gw6.00033   chr9:  cn=0            0
# 10 gw6.00033   chr10  cn=0            0
```

**Edit:** Check if it is working...

```
res[ res$Chr_No == "chr10", ]
#   Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
# 1 gw6.00033   chr10  cn=0            0
# 2 gw6.0006    chr10  cn=0            3

res[ res$Chr_No == "chr1:", ]
#   Sample_Name Chr_No Copy_No Frequence
# 1 gw6.00033   chr1:  cn=0            1
# 2 gw6.0006    chr1:  cn=0            1
```

Comment: Its not working.In data frequency of chromosome10 is 3 but in Result it's 0

Comment: Yes, It's working, Thank You. That time It was my mistake.  I apologize for that comment.

Comment: @RochiSaurabh no problem, accept/upvote if it was useful, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: How can I arrange these Chromosomes in ascending order (chr1, chr2, chr3....)with there frequencies?

Comment: @RochiSaurabh see edit, we need to create ordered factor vector.